# How to use this script to redirect user?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

```
var GOOGLE_API_KEY = "mykey";
var geocoder;
if (navigator.geolocation) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successFunction, errorFunction);
}
function successFunction(position) {
  var lat = position.coords.latitude;
  var lng = position.coords.longitude;
}
function errorFunction() {
  alert ("Geocoder failed");
}
function reverseGeoCoding(lat, lng) {
    var geoCodingUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json? latlng=" + lat + "," + lng + "&key=" + GOOGLE_API_KEY
    return $.get(geoCodingUrl)
}
reverseGeoCoding(lat, lng)
    .then(function(data) {
      var address = results[6].formatted_address;
      if (address == "Mumbai, India") {
        window.location = "url";
      } 
      if(address == "Bangalore, India"){
        window.location = "url";
      } 
      if(address == "Jaipur, India") {
        window.location = "url";
      }
      else{
        window.location = "url";
      }
    });
```

I wanted to utilise this script to redirect users based on the address retrieved by making use of Google's API. However, console error message says variable 'lat' cannot be found?

Comment: lat nor lng is ever defined

Comment: You never defined lat or lng in a scope where it can be used by other functions.

Comment: I thought I could make use of lat that was defined in the success function. Do I explicitly define it again?

Comment: Create references in an outer scope and write the values to these.

Comment: Search quick intro to javascript. It'll take 5 minutes of reading to see what's going on.

Comment: Do I just declare them as global variables?

Answer (score 0):

You should do this:

```
function successFunction(position) {
  var lat = position.coords.latitude;
  var lng = position.coords.longitude;
  reverseGeoCoding(lat, lng).then(function(data) {
    var address = results[6].formatted_address;
    if (address == "Mumbai, India") {
      window.location = "url";
    } 
    if(address == "Bangalore, India"){
      window.location = "url";
    } 
    if(address == "Jaipur, India") {
      window.location = "url";
    }
    else{
      window.location = "url";
    }
  })
}
```

Or declare it as global variables

Comment: "successFunctionpublic_html:38TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'reverseGeoCoding(lat, ing)" - both approaches led to this error.